# File System Types in .Net

Tags: .net, filesystems, directory, path

I don't get the abstractions and the terminology :-(

For example, DirectoryInfo.FullName is defined as the full path of the directory or file, but it's a string! So is DirectoryInfo.Name, FileInfo.FullName, Path.GetDirectoyName and so on.

This means that in .Net there is no "depth" (or "meat" - my English isn't so good) for the file system objects. There's no protection from a type system. I can't, for example, define two Path objects and ask if one of them is "above" the other - I have to manipulate the strings. I can't differentiate between a Path that identifies a directory and a path that identifies a file. I can't do anything!-( Just manipulate strings.

Is this correct (or am I simply missing something). If correct, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the `Path` class and the `Uri` class.

MSDN links:

[Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)

[Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

For example with the `Path` class you have methods to get only the directory, only the filenam or even only the filename without the extension for a given path.

With the `Uri` class you have a property to tell you if it's an absolute `Uri` (`IsAbsoluteUri`) and a method to make a relative `Uri` (`MakeRelativeUri`). Check the [Uri FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/ncl/archive/2010/02/23/system-uri-f-a-q.aspx) for further information.

---

Example for traversing a path from top to bottom:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);

    dir = dir.Parent;
} while (dir != null);
```

Comment: I feel better about the Uri - there not everything is a string, but for the file system?

Comment: @Avi, the `Uri` is useful when you want to make relative paths. Beside that, I stick with `Path`, `DirectoryInfo`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx). To find out if you have a file, you can do `Path.GetFileName("C:\\test\\") == String.Empty`. Or if you are sure the file has an extension you can use `Path.HasExtension`.

Comment: Thanks, Yuriy, but there again: First, there is no Path object. And, it's not typesafe - everything is a string. Even the example they provide starts with:

        string path1 = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        string path2 = @"c:\temp\MyTest";
        string path3 = @"temp";

But a path isn't a string - see my comment to scottm below.

Answer (score 1):

I think the typesafe objects for FS entities are `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` themselves.

Comment: Re my comment to scottm, these are the types for the nodes on the graph, not for the "road from one node to another"

Answer (score 0):

What is a file path anymore than a string? You can use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class to manipulate the strings. The DirectoryInfo class also has a [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx) to get it's parent directory, and FileInfo has a [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties.aspx) property to get it's current directory. What else do you need?

Comment: I think on the file system as a forest of directed trees with two types of nodes (directories which can have children, and files which can't) and one type of labeled edges. A Path is NOT a string. It's a traversal of the tree from one node to another! A path HAS-A corresponding string - the concatenation of all the labels along its edges. 

Thus, for example, I could define an operation on a path such as "GoingUp" or "GoingDown".

Comment: IMHO, the path itself is a string representation of the location of a file/directory in the node tree.